# "You may only load 1 post body every second" - Why is this neccasary?

Tags: discussion

What is is the "You may only load 1 post body every second" message, this issue occurs in the tab votes ([stackexchange/users/userid/username?tab=votes])[1](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/id/username?tab=votes)

I searched for it and found https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20604/what-to-do-with-you-may-only-load-the-closed-dialog-every-3-seconds. It is not really the same.

I then tried to reproduce it myself using the "DéjàClick" addon, and did record it on a video (https://streamable.com/g64mz).

Why should i only be able to load a post just every second?

Comment: Most likely a Denial-of-Service prevention of some sort.

Answer (score 3):

It's just badly implemented rate limiting. The intention is to prevent accidental or intentional denial of service by triggering a number of expensive database queries. The reason I say the implementation is bad is that it does not conform to standard practices, which would be to configure a burst limit like 5 loads per 5 seconds to provide the same level of protection without causing the UX issue you see.

The same thing is done for votes (the system considers creating bounties, flagging, voting up or down, and voting to close to be of the internal "vote" type), viewing post scores, and more.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to prevent denial of service, either accidental or deliberate. This helps ensure our millions of visitors worldwide can keep using the site.

Comment: Yes, or maybe to prevent trivial scraping?

Comment: @AviD Not scraping, because this only applies to the AJAX queries on the vote page which load a sample of the post. This involves an expensive database query. Scraping on the other hand is done by loading pages _directly_, which accesses existing pre-rendered HTML. The rate limits for scraping are much higher because it requires fewer resources, and are (I believe) imposed by their caching CDN.